# Is it possible to access past iOS logs?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, development, logs

I know that you can get live logs from XCode, LemonJar, or `cfgutil`, but these are all in real time.  Is there any way to access logs from before the phone was plugged into the computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect all logs to a file so that you can see it when needed. So you can resolve any issues come in future.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756592/how-to-get-old-console-log

Comment: This will only work while the phone is plugged into the computer though, right? I'm looking for logs from before the phone was plugged in.

Comment: Performing a `sysdiagnose` (via the procedure discussed above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616816 ) will capture any device logs _at that time_, even if the device isn't currently near a computer. It can be downloaded later, or accessed via 'Settings > Privacy > Analytics & Improvements > Analytics Data > sysdiagnose_2023.01.01_... ' (e.g. on iOS 14) and saved via the 'Share' menu as desired. (Un-used 'sysdiagnose' archives are automatically purged after a couple of days, so save it somewhere if you might want it!)